# Google AdSense reloading?

Tags: cookies, web, adsense

Please tell me something about Google AdSense:

1) Can i reload ads by myself without full-page-reloading? For example refresh AdSense frame or call some script?

2) About "interest-based advertising" that works around cookies. Can i influence on it for setting my own interest-keywords? How works this mode?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT Oct 2014: See my note below the answer to the first question.*

1. No. You cannot currently (December 2012) refresh ads without reloading the page.
   AdSense Premiere accounts can do this (you can't apply for this program -- they will contact you about joining if you have hundreds of millions of pageviews per month only). There was an AdSense for AJAX beta program that did what you are talking about it, but it was cancelled.

*Added Oct 2014 -- You **can** do this and stay in accordance with TOS by putting your AdSense in DFP units. DFP does have a call to refresh ads. See https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/3058726?hl=en*

2. I think you are saying you want to affect the genre/topic of ads on your site. You can do this to some extent by using the AdSense Section Targeting tags. You can use these tags in your page code to tell the AdSense scraper bot that certain parts of the content are more important or less important to the page. For example, if you had a site about how to write speeches, the content of the sample speeches you would provide on the site would be irrelevant to the user for ads. You would want ads to do with public speaking, writing, etc. If you had a sample speech about cars, you wouldn't want ads about cars on the page. So you would use section targeting to tell AdSense to ignore the sample speech itself.

You can't use this method to have ads on a topic completely separate from your page.

Read more here: http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=23168